# Drag custom view onto window in Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm coming from the world of C# and Winforms where I can build a custom UserControl and drag it onto a form as if it were a common control. Is there a way to do that in Xcode and Interface Builder?

I've only seen how to set the view at runtime but I'd like to see it on my window at design time. For example, I'd expect my custom view to be listed in the available controls.

Thanks!

Simon

Comment: There is a custom view in IB, just drag it in.

Comment: @rdelmar - how do I associate the custom view with my actual view? Right now I just see a box that says "Custom View".

Comment: Have the custom view selected, and then in the identity inspector, you set its class to your NSView subclass.

Comment: Okay I've done that but the view isn't appearing at runtime. At design-time I can see the view control labeled "HelloView". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Something must have been screwed up with my original view because I couldn't get it to work. I created a new one from scratch and it worked! Although is it still true that I can't see my view on the parent window at design time?

Comment: What do mean your view doesn't show up at design time?  Don't you see a blue rectangle when you drag it in?

Comment: Sorry - I should be more clear. I see the blue rectangle but I don't see any of the controls that are part of that view until runtime. Does that make sense?

Comment: How are you putting the controls in?  In code?  If so, you won't see any of them until runtime.

Comment: I'm dragging in a custom view and setting the class to MyCustomViewClass. But then I only see a rectangle that says "MyCustomViewClass". I don't see any of the controls from MyCustomViewClass.

Comment: You shouldn't if you are defining those controls in code (if you're talking about seeing them in IB).

Answer (score 6):

**Interface Builder** doesn't add (or allow the addition of, now that IB Plugins are derelict) Custom Objects to the Object Library. You can only drag in existing/preset objects, but you **can** have IB instantiate them as instances of a subclass as long as they are instantiated the same way.

E.g. **Drag in a custom view and set the class to** `MyCustomViewClass`, **or drag in a scroll view and set the class to** `MyCustomScrollView`, **or drag in an object and set the class to** `CustomObject`, et cetera.

And that is the preferred way of using custom controls in Interface Builder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically just ripping off rdelmar's comment... but I thought a picture would be helpful[image]

Drag a normal view into IB, then select it and do this.

Answer (score 1):

Every Window you create in IB has a view on it as its first subcomponent.  You dont need to create a separate custom view for it.  If you really are subclassing it just change the class name in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been mentioned in this thread about adding your custom view's name to the view controller's `XIB` file, you will need to *override* `initWithCoder` in your custom view.